# Passing value inside a for loop to outside of the for loop windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to get the value of variable a that is inside the for loop.
For my below code i tried to get the value out into variable h.. 
But the value of a become null..
Can anyone help me with passing the value out of the for loop?

```
string imageFileName = App.imagePath;

string a;

object b;
sting h;

int i;
string noteSeparate;

private void Library_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{


    if (MainListBox.Items.Count == 0)
    {

        //To save the separated note by '^'
        string[] noteSeparated;
        //Read the file and display it line by line.
        IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //Read the note saved in myFile.txt
        StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ViewFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore));

            try
            {

                String fileText = readFile.ReadLine();
                //noteSeparated is the variable that save the retrieve note from myFile.txt and is noteSeparated by '^'
                noteSeparated = fileText.Split(new char[] { '^' });

                for (i = 0; i < noteSeparated.Length; i = i + 3)
                {
                  noteSeparate = noteSeparated[i];
                  a = noteSeparate;
                }

                h = a;
                readFile.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                noNoteBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you check whether the for loop gets executed ?

Comment: yes the loop did execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a break; clause immediately after assigning a = noteSeparated[i];.

Comment: something like...
a = noteSeparated[i];
                        break;

Comment: now i can get the value out..
Can u help me with another thing?? i am stuck at..


The text in isolated file is in the format of "noteTitle^note^imagePath^noteTitle^note^imagePath^...." and so on.. I am trying to retrieve all the noteTitle only. For the the variable a inside the for loop i get 0,3,... but for the a outside of the for loop return me a null value(6).

Can help me with getting all the noteTitle only?  using the above code

Comment: Use a List<string> to accumulate the values. You will need two nested loops. Be sure to let us know how we scored doing your assignment.

Comment: Give @kanchirk credit for this answer and post your other question separately (with the updated code). It's hard to answer questions with code in comments.